# How can I convert bool true or false to string "True" or "False"

Tags: c#

Is there a simple way for me to convert bool true or false to string "True" or "False". I know I can do this with some if logic but I am wondering if there is something even simpler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) structure has a `ToString()` method. So:

```
bool b = true;
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
```

Answer (score 8):

Call ToString()

```
System.Console.WriteLine(false.ToString());
System.Console.WriteLine(true.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the values `true` and `false` you can use `Convert.ToString`

```
Convert.ToString(true) // "True"
```

**EDIT**: mattn has the better answer, I was translating code from VB where the `True` keyword did not have a `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

To simply print "True" / "False", there are built in static readonly fields on `Boolean` type:

```
string falseString = bool.FalseString;
string trueString = bool.TrueString;
```

Not that the value of bools might change in future or directly answers OP's question, but just adding some related info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean_fields(v=vs.100).aspx